# Proper use of classes in web development

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, web

I used to write winforms and now I am trying to port some of my apps to web interface, but my apps seems to be not working, althought the code in my class did not change.

I have never done web development, so I am wondering if this is something what I am not doing right?

I use this code in my runEbay.aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="runEbay.aspx.cs" Inherits="eBay_Item_Scanner.runEbay" %>

<div>
    <a href="Default.aspx">Home</a> | <a href="runEbay.aspx">Run Full eBay Scan WARNING!!!!!!!
    </a>
</div>
<%
    string MAINPN = Request["MAINPN"] != null ? Request["MAINPN"] : "";
    string EBAYCATEGORYTOSCAN = Request["EBAYCATEGORYTOSCAN"] != null ? Request["EBAYCATEGORYTOSCAN"] : "";

    Response.Write("<br>MAINPN: " + MAINPN);
    Response.Write("<br>EBAYCATEGORYTOSCAN: " + EBAYCATEGORYTOSCAN);

    //create instance of class Program    
    eBay_Item_Scanner.Program eb = new eBay_Item_Scanner.Program();

    if (SUBPN.Length > 0)
    {
        String query = @"my query using some request parameters";

        //call functions from another class
        eb.getEbay_com_API(query, EBAYCATEGORYTOSCAN);
    }    
    Response.Write("<br><br>Scanning is done");          
%>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>


    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why not? What happens? What error do you get? What's the class?

Comment: The code behind is your friend.  Please embrace it.

Comment: In this case you wan't see what you expect for many reasons. First move your code/page/stuff inside the body tag. Second...don't assume HTML processing is SO procedural. Naive pipeline: on server the page is loaded, code is executed (in sequence), output HTML is rendered and sent to client. Client gets and display the page, all together.

Comment: A small tip: web development and desktop development are very different. Go back to a simple example, a tutorial and start from the beginning (and save your time: do not think/compare to WinForms).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK; the problem was that my functions were too big and they timed out the IIS. I removed the timeout and that solved the problem.